# Excel - Alternative for COUNTA()?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a program that calculate slopes and intercepts from multiple sets of data imported from a .csv file. The ranges of those sets of data are dynamic. They can change based on the data itself.

To calculate the slope, and intercept of each set considering the dynamic ranges, I´m using

```
=INDEX(LINEST(INDIRECT("B3:B"&COUNTA(B:B)+1),INDIRECT("A3:A"&COUNTA(A:A))),1)
=INDEX(LINEST(INDIRECT("B3:B"&COUNTA(B:B)+1),INDIRECT("A3:A"&COUNTA(A:A))),2)
```

However, The program is taking too much time (more than 2 min) to perform the calculations, since I have 12 sets of data of around 1000 points.

I noticed that if I simply used the operation below, without considering the dynamic range, defined by `COUNTA()`, the calculation finishes in about 5s.

```
=INDEX(LINEST(B3:B998,A3:A998),1)
=INDEX(LINEST(B3:B998,A3:A998),1)
```

In the macro I tried doing something like:

```
Range("C3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX(LINEST(R[0]C[-1]:R[p-o]C[-1],R[0]C[-2]:R[p-o]C[-2]),1)"
```

Where p and o are qual to the end and beginning of my dynamic range given by:

```
Sheets("Ranges").Activate
    o = Cells(4, 3).Value
    p = Cells(4, 4).Value
```

But It didn´t work. I guess I don´t really understand how R1C1 works

Can you help me come up with a solution for this?

Comment: I think I understand - you're using `o` and `p` to help set the `R[]` value in R1C1?  You need to close the formula, put those values, then reopen it. `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(LINEST(R[0]C[-1]:R[" & p-o & "]C[-1],R[0]C[-2]:R[" & p-o & "]C[-2]),1)"` should do the trick

Comment: Do you really need to use Select and Activate in your macro?

Comment: Instead of using INDIRECT which is volatile, try using INDEX: `=INDEX(LINEST(B3:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)+1),A3:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))),1)`